# Trouble installing specific .tar.bz2

Tags: software-installation, compiling, install-from-source, tar

I've used Ubuntu for over a year now and I have never gotten the hang of tarballs.

I have a .tar.bz2, I've extracted it but I can't figure out where to go from here. I tried running `./configure` but I got `No such file or directory`.

There's a folder called `config`; I'm not sure of the significance of that, though, or what I should do with it.

There's no README or anything like that.

Any ideas?

**Edit** Here's the directory hierarchy:

```
config
  wl.mk
  wlconfig_lx_shared
  wlconfig_nomimo
  wl_default
  wl_hnd

linux
  wl_ap.o
  wl_apsta.o
  wl_sta.o
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to install?

Comment: What package is this? What files and folders are in the `.tar.bz2`? You should try and follow instructions from where you got the package.

Comment: Can you please extract the archive and include in the question the file list of this archvie?
You can do this by running `ls` into the directory where you extract the archive and posting the output.

Comment: I've added the directory's contents to my post.

Comment: Those are modules for wifi (BCM4312?) or router (dd-wrt) or somehing like that. Please include such information next time you ask something. And also show us where you got it from please.

Comment: @Whatever All of the comments asked for specific information in order to improve the post and make it useful to the community. Thank you for responding to the request from PeppeDAlterio. Please help us help you by responding to the others as well

Answer (score 0):

A "tarball" is the archive format output by the `tar` command (`man tar`). It can contain files, directories, files in directories, ...

A file called `something.tar.bz2` is **probably** a tar archive, compressed with `bzip2` (`man bzip2`). You can check with the `file` command (`man file`).

You can see the contents of `something.tar.bz2` with `tar tvjf something.tar.bz2`, and extract it to the current directory with `tar xjvf something.tar.bz2`. After you have extracted the files (and directories, and ...) is the time to look for `README`, `INSTALL`, or whatever, to hint at the next step.